# String with template, dynamic variables

Tags: javascript

How to get effect like this?

```
name = 'Mark';
template = 'Your name is {{name}}';
console.log(template); // return "Your name is Mark";
name = 'John';
console.log(template); // return "Your name is John"
```

How to make some kind of easy template system for strings? Maybe function that will find for some tags ( {{ }} for example) and replace text inside with current variable? Or some method that is build in JS?

Comment: No need to make one, it already exists ~ https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: @Phil A template string is different than this, where the template string itself can be anything the user defined.

Comment: Fair point, the template literals aren't an interpolation engine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a **very** simplified templating function if you really need it to be dynamic. I don't recommend using this for a production site, as there are templating engines like handlebars, mustache, dust, etc, but this may work for you. You can test it out at this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vw6av0am/

```
function templateMe(template, obj) {
  var regex = /{{(.*?)}}/g;
  return template.replace(regex, function(match, capture) {
    return obj[capture] || "";
  });
}

var template = 'Your name is {{name}}';
var obj = {
  name: "Mark"
};

var output = templateMe(template, obj);
console.log(output);
```

Comment: In case anyone's interested, I made an update to allow for nested attributes in the object you're passing in: https://jsfiddle.net/vw6av0am/1/

Answer (score 3):

Try mustache. 
https://mustache.github.io/mustache.5.html

A typical template would look like this:

```
Hello {{name}}
You have just won {{value}} dollars!
```

The same (custom-templates) can be achieved using react as well, but react uses javascript code in single {} curlies. This allows u to fit logic around ur (template) components. They become reusable across views.